# Springer llncs TOC first page number

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, lncs

I have a toc with 2 pages. The second page has a page number (II), but the first not. What have I to do? I want a page number one the first toc page (I).

Thanks

```
\documentclass[deutsch]{llncs}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\thispagestyle{headings}
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}\tableofcontents
\newpage
\phantomsection
\cleardoublepage 

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\maketitle
```

Comment: This is the default for many document classes... and your example misses some features: `bookmark` or `hyperref` package **and** `\end{document}`

Comment: In any case, keep in mind, that Springer eventually does not like a numbered first ToC page and will reject a hack

Answer (score 5):

The `llncs` class defines `\chapter` to have no page number on the chapter start page. Since `\tableofcontents` is effectively using `\chapter*`, the empty page style applies to the toc starter page too.

This code removes the `\thispagestyle` temporarily for the ToC only.

```
\documentclass[deutsch]{llncs}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\let\classtableofcontents\tableofcontents%

\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \begingroup%
  \xpatchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}{}%
  \classtableofcontents%
  \endgroup%
}

\usepackage{bookmark}



\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}


\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\thispagestyle{headings}
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\phantomsection
\cleardoublepage 

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Alternatively it's possible to use

```
\let\classtableofcontents\tableofcontents%

\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \begingroup%
  \let\origthispagestyle\thispagestyle
  \renewcommand{\thispagestyle}[1]{%
    }
  \classtableofcontents%
  \endgroup%
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Michael Remember that the best way to say thanks in this site is to accept answers that solve your issues. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) for more info.